# Degenerate quantum error correction code

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-error-correction

I have been reading [this](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/ErrorCorrectionSteane06.pdf) to understand quantum error correction a bit.

On page 13, there are paragraphs about degenerate QEC.

It says, if $E_{1}E_{2}  \in H $, $E_1 $ and $E_2$ will have the same syndrome, so are indistinguishable in the syndrome extraction process. However, you can apply the same error correction procedures for both as if they are the same error.

This statement confuses me a lot.

1. How does that statement ($E_{1}E_{2}  \in H $) tell you that they will result in the same syndrome values?
2. I suppose syndrome measurement is all you can do to probe your quantum state. So, if all the syndrome measurements result in the same value, what the individual qubit states actually are does not matter.. but for some reason, this bothers me a bit (probably because my lack of math rigor)

Comment: Hello. Could you define $H$ in the question? Thanks!

Comment: @StarBucK $H$ is the stabilizer of the code space. I guess it's the set consisting of all generators.